# The service "form.type.users" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.context"

Tags: php, symfony, security, console, doctrine

I used in my project symfony2.8. I configured `config.yml` like that:

fos_user:

db_driver: orm

firewall_name: main

user_class: Video\IntelligenceBundle\Entity\Users

from_email:

```
    address: you@example.com

    sender_name: example
```

and `parameter.yml` like that:

parameters:

```
mongodb_server: "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx"

database_host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

database_port: xxxx

database_name: dbtest

mailer_transport: smtp

mailer_host: mail.supremecenter.com

mailer_user: test@example.pro

mailer_password: test

database_user: root

database_password: null
```

But when I run  this command:

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

I get this error:

```
 The service "form.type.users" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.context".
```

services:

```
form.type.users:

    class: Video\IntelligenceBundle\Form\UsersType

    arguments: ["@security.context"]

    tags:

        - { name: form.type, alias: users_type }
```

Comment: Please don't share text in images. Additionally, what is the definition of the service `form.type.users`?

Comment: thank you @NicoHaase ,this is the definition  :
    form.type.users:
        class: Video\IntelligenceBundle\Form\UsersType
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: users_type }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the upgrade notes at https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements - that service has been deprecated since Symfony 2.6 and you need to check which parts (either the token storage service `security.token_storage` giving you access to the currently logged in user, or the service `security.authorization_checker` to check for permissions) are actually needed in your form.

But as this should not be a blocker if you are using Symfony 2.8: are you sure that you are really using that version and not a more recent one? Nevertheless, it should not be wrong to refactor your code to these new services